# Taking full page screenshot with a Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is there away to capture a screenshot of the full page, including what is below the fold, in a Chrome Extension?

The [captureVisibleTab](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html) seems to be limited to what is displayed within the visible area.

Comment: Please see this i want to get all tabs screenshot https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65786002/embed-js-code-in-the-for-loop-of-the-tabs-array-to-get-full-window-length-page-j

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're limited to capturing the visible page via captureVisibleTab unless you use Flash or NPAPI.

Comment: is it still limited? or they've given permission to capture fullpage?

Answer (score 8):

The standard approach seems to be to scroll around the page and capture screenshots at each part and then stick them all together. The official google screen capture plugin does this, but I found it to be buggy (at least on Mac OSX), so I wrote my own [full page screen capture extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/full-page-screen-capture/fdpohaocaechififmbbbbbknoalclacl).

Source code [here](https://github.com/mrcoles/full-page-screen-capture-chrome-extension) (relevant code in page.js and popup.js).

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is working in most cases. but for e.g. https://news.google.co.in/ for this url, on left side there is a tree of top stories, it gets repeated. Any help in that area?

Comment: Hi @MrColes am facing issue when call full screenshot Unchecked runtime.lastError: This request exceeds the MAX_CAPTURE_VISIBLE_TAB_CALLS_PER_SECOND quota.

Answer (score 2):

On Macs, while not a Chrome extension, you can use the following AppleScript to automate the process found here:

https://zapier.com/blog/full-page-screenshots-in-chrome/

```
tell application "Google Chrome" to activate
  tell application "System Events"
  keystroke "i" using {option down, command down}
  delay 0.3
  keystroke "p" using {shift down, command down}
  delay 0.3
  keystroke "Full"
  delay 0.5
  key code 76
end tell
```

Open ScriptEditor and paste that script in. Save it as a file wherever you need it locally. When you run it by pressing play in ScriptEditor, it will automatically save a full screenshot of the active tab to your Downloads folder.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome 59 adds a new feature in DevTools called [Capture full-size screenshot](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/devtools-release-notes#screenshots). But I don't know whether this API can be called by extensions.

Comment: It should be possible to call it using `chrome.debugger` API. But that's a big hammer.

Comment: adding to @Xan 's comment : [Chrome DevTools Protocol Viewer](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Page/#method-captureScreenshot) is this relevant ?

**edit :** it did not help. still gave the same small screenshot.

Comment: @Xan what do you mean by "that's a big hammer"?

Comment: @Ashavsky It's a permission that allows you to do practically anything to any page, will have scary warnings on install, will have a persistent "Extension is attached to this page" warning on top while running, and will fail if Dev Tools are open (or interfere with them). Unless you literally are trying to implement an alternative to Dev Tools, this permission is _too strong_.

Comment: @Xan thanks for the clarification, certainly not what I am looking to do!

Comment: It's not possible to use this with the `chrome.debugger`. I was not able to find a command correspondent to a full page screenshot and the available one `Page.captureScreenshot` takes only a small screenshot.

Comment: Hi @MrColes am facing issue when call full screenshot

Unchecked runtime.lastError: This request exceeds the MAX_CAPTURE_VISIBLE_TAB_CALLS_PER_SECOND quota.

Comment: Note to anyone interested in using this tool, this is chrome.debugger.sendCommand( Page.captureScreenshot ) neither this nor the actual GUI full size screenshot work reliably. Page.captureScrnshot has a param captureBeyondViewport which just stitches the same image over and over (its in experimental phase). You are better off handling this in backend, or just using scrolling and visibleTab capture