# Full scroll screenshot CHROME EXTENSION

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, screenshot

I want to capture full page scroll screenshot in my chrome extension. I use code below, but it only captures what i see on screen, but i want to capture full scrolled page. Can someone help me please? thanks in advance.

background.js:

```
  chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(null, null, function(dataUrl) {  
})
```

Comment: [Taking full page screenshot with a Chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13293720)

Answer (score 0):

Download screen capture from app store then follow instructions:
Step 1:
Go to the Chrome Web store and search for "screen capture" in the search box.

Step 2:
Select the "Screen Capture (by Google)" extension and install it.

Step 3:
After installation, click on the Screen Capture button on the Chrome toolbar and select Capture Whole Page or use the keyboard shortcut, Ctrl+Alt+H.

Step 4:
You'll see Chrome scrolling down to capture the whole page and once finished, an options bar will display above the Web page that allows annotations, sharing, and saving the capture.

Answer (score 0):

Please include the below script before  tag

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/1.3.8/FileSaver.min.js"></script>
```

And include this:

FileSaver.js

```
html2canvas(document.body, {onrendered: function(canvas){canvas.toBlob(function(blob){ saveAs(blob, "wholePage.png");});}});
```